# Display container on full page

Tags: html, css

EDIT: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C8UUt/)

I have set

```
html{
height: 100%;
}
```

And

```
body{
min-height: 108%;
}
```

I want to show the `content` to full height to the `footer` even if `content` is empty.

This is `container`
[image]

And this is `content`

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a jsfiddle of your code? It would make it a lot easier to see your code and help out.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/C8UUt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by adding `height:100%` in addition to the `min-height:108%` to you `body` element:

http://jsfiddle.net/C8UUt/1/

```
body {
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

    background: #42413C;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
    min-height: 108%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

#### Update

To make the `sidebar1` full height you can use a little trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/C8UUt/3/

```
.container {
    width: 960px;
    background: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative; // added this to tell position:absolute that this is his parent
}

.sidebar1 {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    background: #EADCAE;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%; // to make it 100% height
    position: absolute; // added this so it will take `min-height` of parent into account
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 780px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* float: left; */
    height: inherit;
    margin-left: 180px; // since position:absolute doesn't take part in the normal flow, we must account for that space manually
}
```

Comment: Right. Can you please tell how to make sidebar1 to full height to the footer.

Comment: Updated post to answer your question.

Comment: One more question if you would like to answer.

Why there page is ALREADY scrolling even it does not have any overflowed content?

Comment: Because you set `min-height:108%` on body. Was that a typo ?

Comment: sorry for my lack of knowledge. TYPO?
if I set height:100% of BODY, same result.

Comment: Typo= mistake of typing. I said if you remove `min-height: 108%;` from body it will work.

Comment: 108% is TYPO, output is the same if I 

min-height: 100%;

Or I remove it completely.

Comment: Look: http://jsfiddle.net/C8UUt/4/ I set `min-height` to 100% on `body` and there is not scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

if your browser supports CSS3 use this:

```
.container {height:100vh;}
```